# Is there need to create external AngularJS/JSP/JSF for hyperledger-fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

- I am working on hyperledger composer
- after deploy bna file to server it will automatically create angular UI when we connect to angular through fabric server
- now my question is is there need to create jsp/angular/jsf whatever files to dispaly UI(client) like login web pages or it will automatically generate???

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the angular generator via Yo, then what is generated is a simple angular example. It's intention is not to generate a complete working application but to provide you with a starting point from which you can tailor to meet your needs. For example the generator can only handle simple models and cannot handle models that contain concepts. It can only interact with a rest server that doesn't have authentication enabled or multi-user enabled.

In answer to your specific question about login pages, it won't, you will have to add this kind of capability yourself.

Comment: The $syscollectionsAsset:org.acme.vehicle.auction.VehicleListing document does not exist.  VehicleListing is my asset and i have created some queries and functions in composer fabric deployed on fabric server and tried run on rest server all are fine..coming to couch DB when i click on this funcion names or asset names it is showing error which i have provided above..can you please tell me the reason